# how to access custom configuration information from the globa.php in Zend framework 2

Tags: zend-framework2

I can't seem to understand how to access custom configuration data I have in global.php in my controller.  I'm using zf2.  Whenever I try:

```
$config = $this->getServiceLocator()->get('config');
```

I get the following error:

```
Fatal error: Call to a member function get() on a non-object
```

I know it has something to do with the service manager/locator but I'm very new to ZF2 and the whole DI ethos.  I'm totally stuck and need a simple example as to how to configure the SM to allow it to be accessed to pull out my custom config values.  Below is my module.config.php  I have no idea what to put in the empty array.  I'm not using any database.  I want to store ldap options in global.php that I can access in a controller and pass to a model to create a new ldap instance.

```
<?php
class Module
{
    public function getConfig()
    {
        return include __DIR__ . '/config/module.config.php';
    }

    public function getAutoloaderConfig()
    {
        return array(
            'Zend\Loader\StandardAutoloader' => array(
                'namespaces' => array(
                    __NAMESPACE__ => __DIR__ . '/src/' . __NAMESPACE__,
                ),
            ),
            'Zend\Loader\ClassMapAutoloader' => array(
              __DIR__ . '/autoload_classmap.php',
            ),
        );
    }

    public function getServiceConfig()
    {
      return array();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Accessing the getServiceConfig method in the constructor results in a null object.  I moved

```
$config = $this->getServiceLocator()->get('config');
```

to the get method the controller and was able to access the config data I needed.

Comment: Ah, that you were calling it in the constructor was a vital piece of missing info Rodney :) Services, including the ServiceManager itself are injected by way of initializers and that happens after the object is instantiated. Not having access to it in the constructor would be considered expected behaviour.